# PyQt5 QTreeWidget output to multiple columns

Tags: pyqt5, qtreewidget

I connect .ui  file to .py script

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
def __init__(self, *args):
    super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args)
    loadUi('ui.ui', self)
```

now i can get access  to QTreeWidget, named treeWidget1:

```
self.treeWidget1
```

How i can output to multiple columns separately filename and extension?

I was find some example, but here output only to fist column:

```
    for i in self.filesList1:
        if i.lower().endswith(tuple(ext_pattern)) and os.path.isfile(os.path.join(self.folder1, i)):
            row = os.path.splitext(i)
            self.treeWidget1.insertTopLevelItems(0, [QTreeWidgetItem(self.treeWidget1, ["%s" % i])])
```

Answer (score 0):

To add multiple columns for each row, use:

```
self.treeWidget1.insertTopLevelItems(0, [QTreeWidgetItem(self.treeWidget1, ["col1", "col2", "col3"])
```

Replace `"col1"` etc. with appropriate strings derived from your filename.

Note: using `insertTopLevelItems(0, ...)` will insert each item sequentially at the top of the tree. You might want to consider using:

```
self.treeWidget1.addTopLevelItem([QTreeWidgetItem(self.treeWidget1, ["col1", "col2", "col3"])])
```

Instead to preserve the order of `self.filesList1`.